# Laravel - (1/1) FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected '?' in LaravelLocalization.php line 896

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

Everything was working well but after doing composer update, I am facing this error

> **FatalErrorException** syntax error, **unexpected** '?' in
>   LaravelLocalization.php line 896 ",

what is wrong? I'm using mcamara/laravel-localization package

Comment: What version of `laravel-localizatio` did you install? What PHP version are you running?

Comment: I installed "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.3" [https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization], and I am using PHP 7.1.22

Comment: This error is caused by incorrect PHP version, make sure it's really PHP7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked that line inside the code of the package - the error is caused by the **??** operator introduced with PHP7 (http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). It seems you're using an older version of PHP - try switching to version **1.2** of this package.